# Android spelling game

Tags: android, educational, keyboard, speech-synthesis, keyboard-listener

I am looking for an Android game whereby I can connect am external keyboard to my Android tablet and have a one-year old have the names of the keyboard keys be sounded out in the selected language for the keyboard.

It would be nice if the app also implemented a spelling game.

Where can I find such an app?

Thanks.